# Showing a link in Servlet.java

Tags: java

I am using the Eclipse IDE, using a Dynamic Web Project. I created a Servlet, HelloServlet.java and an index.jsp file.

I need to show a link within the JSP file. I have tried the following:

```
request.getWriter().println("<a href='http://localhost:8080/WebApp-01/'> Test </a>");
```

However, nothing produces. What might I do to produce a link in the JSP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing to the Request object rather than the response object. You might wanna try this :

```
 response.setContentType("text/html");
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

 out.println("<a href='http://localhost:8080/WebApp-01/'> Test </a>");
```

Comment: Thanks. Evidently, I was forgot to set the content type.

Comment: Is there a way I can dynamically get that page?

Comment: @user3534092 what do you mean by dynamically ?